# Given a list of integers, find the number of pairs that are consecutive

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to solve this problem that given a list of integers, find the number of pairs that are consecutive.

For example, given the list, [1, 2, 5, 8]:

the pairs that can be formed from the given list are (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8), (2, 5), (2, 8), (5, 8);
the only pair that has consecutive integers is (1, 2) and hence the value to be returned is one (1).

My code is below which didn't pass the test cell which contains L1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Does anyone know how to fix this code in order to return all of the consecutive number pairs from any list?

I received the error below:
Error: AssertionError: Test Case L1 failed
(L1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

```py
def count_pairs(L):
    assert type(L)==list
    res = [(a, b) for idx, a in enumerate(L) for b in L[idx + 1:]]
    for i in range(0,len(res)):
        if abs(res[i][0]-res[i][1]) ==1:
            print((res[i][0],res[i][1]))
    return len([(res[i][0],res[i][1])])
```

Comment: `return len([(res[i][0],res[i][1])])` you probably meant to return some sort of count here

Comment: Also very related (I believe this is the same problem but with a different constant): https://stackoverflow.com/q/61062583/208273

Comment: You are not returning the count of consecutive pair. Set up a counter before looping `res` and increment it by one each time a consecutive pair is found. And finally return the counter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is in the last line of the count_pairs function, where you are only returning a list containing a single consecutive pair instead of the count of all consecutive pairs. To fix this, you can remove the square brackets around the pair and just return the length of the list of consecutive pairs.

Here is the updated code for it:

```
def count_pairs(L):
    assert type(L) == list
    res = [(a, b) for idx, a in enumerate(L) for b in L[idx + 1:]]
    consecutive_pairs = [(x, y) for (x, y) in res if abs(x - y) == 1]
    for pair in consecutive_pairs:
        print(pair)
    return len(consecutive_pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get all the pairs using `itertools.combinations` and then filter it. A better way is to first `.sort()` the list and just compare the adjacent items:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def count_pairs_one(lst):
    return sum(1 for i, j in combinations(lst, r=2) if abs(i - j) == 1)

def count_pairs_two(lst: list):
    lst.sort()
    return sum(1 for i in range(len(lst) - 1) if (lst[i + 1] - lst[i]) == 1)

tests = [
    [1, 2, 5, 8],
    [3, 5, 6, 10],
    [1, 7, 3, 6, 4],
]

for test in tests:
    print(count_pairs_one(test), count_pairs_two(test))
```

**Note:** I assumed there is no duplicate item in the list. If there is, the first approach would return incorrect result because it calculates the duplicate items N times. A fix to that is to pass them to a set like : `set(combinations(lst, r=2))` or if it's huge, you can have a set outside and before calculating, check whether it's a new pair.